# how can we set execl as a default format of ssrs report exporting

Tags: ssrs-2008

i want to set excel as a default export option for SSRS report, can any one do need full[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNtok.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this can be done within the SSRS report manager. There are no properties that I know of to control the export options.

You might be able to create your own interface with C# or VB but that would be a **lot** of work.